# Animation is taking longer to complete than stated duration in anime.js

Tags: anime.js

I'm using anime.js inside a React project. I call this function:

```
  function animate(e: React.SyntheticEvent) {
    const card = e.currentTarget as HTMLDivElement;
    anime({
      targets: card,
      translateX: 285,
      translateY: -574,
      duration: 1000,
      complete: () => {
        console.log('complete');
        console.log(card.offsetLeft, card.offsetTop);
      },
    });
  }
}
```

The `complete` callback returns after 1000ms. The actual animation completes after slightly 2000ms. I get an effect of the card moving slowly for a second, and then speeding off to it's final resting pace.

A reproduction in a separate app with a single component being animated does not show the same behaviour.

Any ideas on what could be happening?

Comment: Is it working properly if you set duration to 1000?

Comment: No, everything is about doubled. Though if I push the number to about 5000ms, then it doesn't quite double